Metric tensor's and stress-energy tensor's interaction with a spin-1 field
The metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$ and stress-energy tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$ are both rank-2 fields. Is it conceivable for these fields to interact with a spin-1 field? In other words, could there be interaction terms like $A_{\mu}A_{\nu}g^{\mu\nu}$ and $A_{\mu}A_{\nu}T^{\mu\nu}$ where $A_{\mu}$ is a spin-1 field? I don't see any problem with that but just want to make sure. To be clear, by $A_{\mu}$, I'm referring to a general spin-1 field not the electromagnetic field.

See the electromagnetic tensor which is a tensorial ("spin-2") representation of a spin-1 field.

$T_{\mu\nu}$ doesn't have any new degrees of freedom, it is constructed out of the fields in the theory. For example, it is determined by the Standard Model. Hence, it doesn't make sense for $T_{\mu\nu}$ to interact with anything. It isn't a field any more than the kinetic term of a Lagrangian is a field. It is built out of fields.
The term $A_{\mu}A_{\nu}g^{\mu\nu}$ is possible, but violates gauge invariance. This is a mass term for the spin-1 gauge field $A_\mu$.

Hi @Nickolas Alves, ok, thanks. To be clear, I was referring to a general spin-1 field not the electromagnetic field but I guess your point would still hold, right? As for the $T_{\mu\nu}$, I can see your point that it's a not field. However, I can't see why it cannot couple to other fields. For example, it DOES couple to graviton in the form $h_{\mu\nu}T^{\mu\nu}$ that's why I have difficulty seeing why it cannot couple to a spin-1 field as $A_{\mu}A_{\nu}T^{\mu\nu}$.

@physics_2015 I don't see how the stress tensor would couple to $A_\mu$ in that way. That new term would also contribute to the stress tensor, and hence modify the stress tensor. This is actually the origin of the nonlinearities in GR. If you are considering a theory of modified gravity, then maybe some of them get a few terms like that (I think torsion gets interactions that resemble this term loosely)

@physics_2015 Notice also that my answer does not assume $A_\mu$ to be the electromagnetic field. Spin-1 fields are always gauge fields, but possibly with gauge symmetry broken (as is the case in the weak sector of the standard model)
